# executeUpdate() hibernate and spring return to controller number of rows

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem with return affected rows in Springmvc/Hibernate project(MySQL databse).

This is my DAO file, which must return the size of affected rows in my database.
When i execute this method in my Controller file always have "null". Maybe this is a problem with threads of hibernate and spring? I must have this row in my Spring controller. Help, if u can.
See below:

```java
@Transactional
public Integer addStudenci(String imie, String nazwisko, String nrIndeksu,
        String email, Integer rok, Integer semestr, String przedmiot,
        String login, String haslo) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "insert ignore into studenci(imiona,nazwisko,nr_indeksu, email, rok, semestr, przedmiot_krztalcenia, login, haslo) values(:imie,:nazwisko,:nrIndeksu,:email,:rok,:semestr,:przedmiot,:login,:haslo)";

    Integer addInt=-1;
    addInt= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query)
            .setParameter("imie", imie).setParameter("nazwisko", nazwisko)
            .setParameter("nrIndeksu", nrIndeksu)
            .setParameter("email", email).setParameter("rok", rok)
            .setParameter("semestr", semestr)
            .setParameter("przedmiot", przedmiot)
            .setParameter("login", login).setParameter("haslo", haslo)
            .executeUpdate();


    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return addInt;
}
```

My service file for this method:

```java
@Transactional
    public Integer addStudenci(String imie, String nazwisko, String nrIndeksu,
            String email, Integer rok, Integer semestr, String przedmiot,
            String login, String haslo) {
        return loginDAO.addStudenci(imie, nazwisko, nrIndeksu, email, rok, semestr,
                przedmiot, login, haslo);
    }
```

This is simple code for reading a number of rows(using method from service)

```js
Integer addNumber = -1;
addNumber = loginService.addStudenci(name_student, nazwisko_student,
nrInd_student, email, rokI, semestrI,
przedmiot_ksztalcenia, login, haslo);
System.console().writer().println(addNumber);
if(1 == addNumber) {
String temat = "Przesłanie hasła do logowania!";
try{
SendMail.Wyslij_maila(email, temat, hasloSend, "System zarządzania projektami na PWR");
}
catch(Exception ex) {
;
}

}
else {
nrInd_student = fields1;
}
```

And i must to know in my Controller the number of records(from this query).

Any idea?

Comment: executeUpdate() returns an int. So it can't return null. Show us the controller code. BTW, why return an Integer rather than an int from your DAO and service methods?

Comment: When i print a variable addNumber in my console see null

Comment: That's simply not possible given the code you posted. But the code is full of bad practices and bugs, so my guess is that what is printed is not printed by the code you posted (Integer instead of int, useless assignment of -1, comparing objects with ==, ignoring exceptions completely, not respecting naming conventions, not indenting the code, etc. etc.)

Comment: Yes, i cut the fragments of code(from my controler method)